# Как правильно использовать метод clone для массива объектов? JAVA

Tags: java, массивы, clone

Необходимо, чтобы при изменении массива arrayTwo, не изменялся массив arrayOne

```
public class Item implements Cloneable {

    public int item;
    Item(int item)
    {
        this.item = item;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException
    {
        return super.clone();
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Item arrayOne[] = {new Item(1), new Item(2), new Item(3)};
        Item arrayTwo[] = arrayOne.clone();
        arrayTwo[0].item = 4;
        for (Item item : arrayOne)
        {
            System.out.println(item.item);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

в данном случае у тебя неглубокое(поверхностное) клонирование, копируются ссылки, т.е. оригинал и клон указывают на один объект в куче.

надо использовать глубокое клонирование - изменить метод сlone

```
@Override
    protected Item clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return (Item) super.clone();
    }
```

и придётся клонировать каждый объект

```
Item[] arrayTwo = {arrayOne[0].clone(), arrayOne[1].clone(),arrayOne[2].clone()};
```

почитай https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/3.13.php для лучшего понимания, или другие статьи сам поищи.